# Indexes and RAM in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I need to write ~147m rows. If I configure my DB without indexes all works well:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NodesRefStop (stop_id text, stop_lat text, stop_lon text,
                stop_id_ref text, stop_lat_ref text, stop_lon_ref text, stop_type_ref text, distance REAL )''')
cur.execute('PRAGMA synchronous = 0')
conn.commit()
```

But if I add indexes sqlite eats all my RAM:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NodesRefStop (stop_id text, stop_lat text, stop_lon text,
                stop_id_ref text, stop_lat_ref text, stop_lon_ref text, stop_type_ref text, distance REAL )''')
cur.execute("CREATE INDEX dist_index ON NodesRefStop (distance);")
cur.execute("CREATE INDEX stop_id_index ON NodesRefStop (stop_id);")
cur.execute('PRAGMA synchronous = 0')
conn.commit()
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never experienced this problem but I was curious and I searched a bit, apparently it's a known issue.

http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Index-memory-usage-in-SQLite-td41624.html

Here an interesting article about sqlite optimizations:
https://katastrophos.net/andre/blog/2007/01/04/sqlite-performance-tuning-and-optimization-on-embedded-systems/

"Try to use indices only on static data or data that changes rarely. Building an index on live or temporary data can be expensive performance-wise."... it's true in every database, not only using sqlite.

If you insert all those rows at the beginning and after data don't change often probably you could try to add the index only at the end. Do you insert all rows in a single transaction? Maybe you could do it in chunks.

Comment: Please include relevant info from your links in the body of the answer itself. Links to third-party sites may break as pages move or the site goes down.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo thanks, you are right. I've just given to the user a couple of links with related info and some general advices hoping to help, it would be too difficult to extract only a piece of info from those articles. He accepted the answer so I guess it was enough for him.